# Conditional average in Python

Tags: python, excel, numpy, xlrd

I am having a problem manipulating my excel file in python. 
I have a large excel file with data arranged by date/time. 
I would like to be able to average the data for a specific time of day, over all the different days; ie. to create an average profile of the *gas_concentrations* over 1 day.

Here is a sample of my excel file:

```
Decimal Day of year     Decimal of day      Gas concentration   
133.6285                    0.6285           46.51230   
133.6493                    0.6493           47.32553   
133.6701                    0.6701           49.88705   
133.691                     0.691            51.88382   
133.7118                    0.7118           49.524 
133.7326                    0.7326           50.37112
```

Basically I need a function, like the AVERAGEIF function in excel, that will say something like 
"Average the *gas_concentrations* when *decimal_of_day*=x"
 However I really have no idea how to do this. Currently I have got this far

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np

book= xlrd.open_workbook('TEST.xlsx')
level_1=book.sheet_by_index(0)

time_1=level_1.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=1088)
dectime_1=level_1.col_values(8, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=1088)
ozone_1=level_1.col_values(2, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=1088)
ozone_1 = [float(i) if i != 'NA' else 'NaN' for i in ozone_1]
```

**Edit**

I updated my script to include the following

```
ozone=np.array(ozone_1, float)
time=np.array(dectime_1)
a=np.column_stack((ozone, time))
b=np.where((a[:,0]<0.0035))
print b
```

**EDIT**
Currently I solved the problem by putting both the variables into an array, then making a smaller array with just the variables I need to average - a bit inefficient but it works!

```
ozone=np.array(ozone_1, float)
time=np.array(dectime_1)
a=np.column_stack((ozone, time))
b=a[a[:,1]<0.0036]
c=np.nanmean(b[:,0])
```

Comment: What is the format of your data ? Are you reading directly the excel file or are you converting it to a csv format ?

Comment: Its in excel - I would rather not have it as csv as I have 5 other corresponding sheets in the file

Comment: In this case I believe that the most difficult part will be to read/write excel files, not computing the average. I have no experience with this, but you could look into package like the ones presented [here](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: I'm already using xlrd which is fine - but I'm stuck on making the conditional averages

Comment: Then you could post the code that you already have : did you manage to get the content of the cells ? match the cells from the same line ? extract all the cells you want to average ? You should probably add to your question what you managed to acheive with xlrd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

```
import numpy as np

data_1 = np.ma.arange(10)
data_1 = np.ma.masked_where(<your if statement>, data_1)

data_1_mean = np.mean(data1)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Getting closer, but I'm not sure how to implement my condition. Currently I put in:                                              `data_1=np.ma.array(ozone_1, float)                                                                       
data_2=np.ma.array(dectime_1, float)
data_1 = np.ma.masked_where(data_2<0.0035, data_1)
data_1_mean = np.nanmean(data_1)`                                                 But this still just gives me the entire average of data_1 instead of a limited average

Comment: that implementation actually looks quite ok to me. Have you checked if you have any NaNs in your `data_1` after applying the condition?

Comment: I think I got rid of the NaNs by applying _nammean_ instead of the normal mean